# MS Access составной ключ

Tags: база-данных, ms-access

Есть БД в MS Access. В таблице есть имя детали и дата обработки детали. В один день не могут обрабатывать больше одной детали одного наименования. Мне надо как-то предусмотреть это при конструировании БД. Я попробовал сделать имя детали основным ключём, а дату просто добавить в индексы (через конструктор таблицы - индексы). Но я всё равно не могу вставить в таблицу два одинаковых наименования детали в разные дни.
Подскажите, как сказать MS Access, что у меня ключ состоит из двух полей? 
По описанию из хелпа не помогло:

1. Откройте таблицу в режиме конструктора.
2. Нажмите кнопку Индексы на панели инструментов.
3. В первой пустой строке столбца Индекс введите имя индекса. Для индекса можно использовать либо имя одного из индексируемых полей,
   либо другое подходящее имя.
4. В поле Имя поля нажмите кнопку раскрытия списка и выберите первое поле, для которого необходимо создать индекс.
5. В следующей строке столбца Имя поля укажите второе индексируемое поле. (Для данной строки поле Индекс оставьте пустым.) Повторите эти
   действия для всех полей, которые необходимо включить в индекс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Выделите в конструкторе таблицы с Ctrl 2 поля для ключа.
2. Поставьте ключ на эти выделенные поля.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]